# Call Intent: choose phone number

Tags: android, android-intent

I start a phone call Intent like this:

```
        String uri = "tel:" + number;
        Intent callintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callintent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
        startActivity(callintent);
```

Can I put more than one phone number in there and let the user pick one to call? 
Can't use the Contacts Activity, the numbers are most likely not in the user's contacs.

Comment: Why not throw up a dialog yourself and let the user pick from there?

Comment: Sure, could do that, I was just wondering if Android has that built in.

Comment: I think it's obtainable with the `putExtra()` method.